# Pollable disruptor

Tags: java, concurrency, low-latency, disruptor-pattern

I did quite a bit of research, but I can not find the solution yet. I would like to find a `pollable ring buffer`, similar to the `LMAX disruptor` one. I have many publishers and one reader.

The problem with `disrupto`r is that it uses its own dedicated thread (pool) to read messages, but i would like to read them from the separate thread, which does other things as well.

One alternative I see is to use `ManyToOneConcurrentArrayQueue` from `agrona` or `MpscArrayQueue` from `jctools`. But neither of these queues `preallocates` objects in the way `LMAX disruptor` does. When I call `ManyToOneConcurrentArrayQueue::offer` or `MpscArrayQueue::offer` I transfer ownership of the object to the queue, and when I call `ManyToOneConcurrentArrayQueue::poll` or `MpscArrayQueue::poll` I take the ownership from them. It is a problem, since it forces me to have a separate object pool for recycling these objects to avoid garbage creation. It is obviously slower than to have `preallocated array` which always keeps an ownership of its contents (a la RingBuffer in LMAX disruptor package).

I wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel and build such a data structure myself, but I couldn't find an existing one either. I will appreciate any help if anybody came across such a structure already.

Comment: What solution did you end up choosing?  I have exactly the same use case (and came here as this is the only internet hit for ManyToOneConcurrentArrayQueue - besides the 10k sites which just scrape github).

Comment: I decided to avoid brain surgery, so I just use MpscArrayQueue and recycle objects. Indeed, it is suboptimal, but async profiler doesn't show this place as a hot spot.

Comment: I did the same - one queue is the 'queue' , another queue passes the objects back to the producer for reuse.  The two queues are the same length, and we prefill the reuse queue on startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disruptor library includes an [EventPoller](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/c21b13a3fcb85431c58406b61468713076f26889/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/EventPoller.java#L6) class

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's pretty nice for GUI applications where certain events have to be handled on a specific thread. For example, in a JavaFX application you can set up continuous polling from an AnimationTimer that gets called once per frame.

Comment: Thank you for idea. I see that EventPoller doesn't have any documentation at all. Here is how it's constructor looks. ```public EventPoller(final DataProvider<T> dataProvider, final Sequencer sequencer, final Sequence sequence, final Sequence gatingSequence)``` How to properly instantiate it? Where do i get all these arguments? If one uses disruptor one doesn't need to manually operate with these classes. Could you pls share a small snippet of code which creates proper EventPoller?

Comment: @Vadim RingBuffer#newPoller is what you want, rather than the constructor. There are a few examples, "PullWithPoller" and "PullWithBatchedPoller", in src/examples of the source repository. It is true that the EventPoller doesn't have a javadoc in the current release; however, there is documentation in the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to use the LMAX disruptors [RingBuffer](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/RingBuffer.java) implementation directly.

Potentially leveraging other parts of the project without starting the *disruptor* as a whole.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about it already. However, RingBuffer is not sufficient for the whole thing to work. One needs a custom pollable implementation of MultiProducerSequencer as well, and i would like to avoid writing it myself if it is already available. Looks like it is not.